# Which of the Divyadesam Sthala are presided by Vishnu's Varaha AvatAram?

Tags: vishnu, temple, sri-vaishnava, alwar

[Divya Desam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divya_Desam) are the group of Vishnu sthalam that are revered by [Azhwargal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvars) in their spontaneous divine poetry - the [Naalayira Divya Prabhandam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naalayira_Divya_Prabhandham). This collection of poetry was collated by Nathamuni, an extraordinary Acharya, gem among gems, of the Sri Vaishnava Sampradayam.

Now for my question:

- Which of the Divya Desam Sthala are ***presided*** by Perumaal in Varaha roopam?

An Exhaustive list would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thiruvidanthai and Thirukalvanur come to mind.  I'm not sure if there are others.

Comment: Tirumala, Simhachalam.

Comment: @moonstar2001 AdiVarahaSwamy at Tirumala is muthal mariyaadai murthy too!

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Sorry. translate?

Comment: @moonstar2001 What i meant is that he is the first to be honored in Tirumala i.e., before visiting Venkateswara Perumaal one visits AdiVarahaSwamy.